# strlen returns wrong value after for loop

Tags: c

If needed , you might run the example code below here:

[Online C compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char *name);
char bar(char c);
 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    foo("Ashcroft");
    return 0;
}

void foo(char *name)
{
    printf("name = %s\n", name);
    int name_length = strlen(name);
    char code[name_length];
    printf("length of name %d\n", name_length);

    for (int i = 0; i < name_length; i++)
    {
        code[i] = bar(name[i]);
    }
    printf("length of code is %ld\n", strlen(code));

    printf("name is %s\n", name);
}

char bar(char c)
{
    return 'a';
}
```

**Problem**

**I expected `length of code` to be the same as `length of name`,
but somehow the length changes after the for loop.**

**Output**

```
name = Ashcroft
length of name 8
length of code is 14
name is Ashcroft
```

**Update**
tried `char code[name_length+1];` but the result is still the same

[image: result]

Comment: Do you know what a null terminator is?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/55dcT199P

Comment: also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Copy the code or console output and paste here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `code` to be just long enough to hold the characters that are part of the string in `name`, but not enough to hold the terminating null byte that strings end with.

So when you pass `code` to `strlen` and `printf`, they read past the end of the array looking for the terminating null byte.  Reading off the end of an array triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case manifests as an unexpected length for the string.

You need to make `code` one element longer to hold the terminating null byte:

```
char code[name_length+1];
```

And also add the null byte after building the string:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < name_length; i++)
{
    code[i] = bar(name[i]);
}
code[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Merely make `code` large enough is insufficient.  The null terminator also needs to be written (perhaps by iterating to `i < name_length + 1`).

Comment: @0___________ Good catch.  Fixed.